# How to stop user from entering a duplicate integer in the vector in (C++)?

Tags: c++

```
    // Using switch statement

    // Vectors & Variables required to store selection and list of items
    vector <int> list_items{};
    char selection{};
    int list_adder{};
    

    do {

        // Displaying Menu Options First:
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "P - Print numbers" << endl;
        cout << "A - Add a number" << endl;
        cout << "M - Display mean of the numbers" << endl;
        cout << "S - Display the smallest number" << endl;
        cout << "L - Display the largest number" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;

        // Storing their choice in the selection variable:


        cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin >> selection;


        switch (selection) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
                cout << "Enter an integer to add to the list: ";
                cin >> list_adder;
                list_items.push_back(list_adder);
                cout << list_adder << " added" << endl;
            break;

        default: 
            cout << "Unknown selection, please try again";
        }

    } while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
```

How do i add a if else or loop or something so if the user already entered for example 5 added , he cant add 5 again, it will say , 5 is already in the list. And they will get the prompt again that "Enter an integer to add to the list. Please help me cant figure this out!

Comment: You have two options: 1. manually check the container for the element and if it is in there, then ask for another number. 2. use a container that does that for you like a `std::set`

Comment: I'm still suck on being unfamiliar with an if-else or for-loop construct, but apparently sparring no difficulties with a switch-case.

Comment: @WhozCraig typo should be stuck; I also do not get the "sparring", but that might be my restricted English skill.

Comment: Please ignore requests for "full code". Anybody who seems to ask for that is actually asking for a [mre], even if they are not aware of it. That is at the same time more and less code than what you have now shown. There is more to the concept than the three words, please study the linked explanation.

Comment: I tried to find the answer for this on the website, but i cant find the answer that's why i posted it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a `vector` to store the list items, you can use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to check if the item already exists in the `vector`. `std::find` returns an iterator to the found item or the `end()` iterator if it was not found.

```cpp
if(std::cin >> list_adder) {
    if(std::find(list_items.begin(), list_items.end(), list_adder) == list_items.end())
        list_items.push_back(list_adder);
    else
        std::cout << "already in the list\n"; 
}
```

Another option is to use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to store the items instead. A `set` can only contain unique values so you don't need to check if the value is already in it before inserting:

```cpp
std::set<int> list_items;
if(std::cin >> list_adder) list_items.insert(list_adder);
```

... but you could check if it's in it if you'd like to inform the user:

```cpp
if(std::cin >> list_adder) {
    if(list_items.contains(list_adder)) std::cout << "already in the list\n";
    else list_items.insert(list_adder);
}
```

---

About `begin()` and `end()` that was asked in the comments:
Most standard container classes have these member functions. They return *iterators*. An iterator is an object (like a pointer) that points to an element inside the container. `begin()` returns an iterator to the first element and `end()` returns an iterator one step after the last element.
To get the actual value from en iterator, you need to *dereference* it:

```
auto it = list_items.begin();
std::cout << *it;             // dereferencing the iterator
```

Note that since `end()` is returning an iterator one step after the last element you are not allowed to dereference it.

A loop using iterators to print all values in your `vector` could look like this:

```
for(auto it = list_items.begin(); it != list_items.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

but nowadays, seeing such loops is rare since you can use range based for-loops instead:

```
for(auto& value : list_items) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: std::find your first solution worked for me thank you

Comment: Can you please explain how its working, what is begin end, i have not reached that far in C++ yet i am having hard time understanding how its working!

Comment: @ABDULLAH- I added some explanations about them to the answer.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, final question - Is this the easiest way to do this logic, which you did at top using std::find, because where i am learning from instructor haven't told me about these things like find, begin,end, set etc, he told me i can try to expand functionality by adding logic which will not allow duplicate entries if user inputed that value again..

Comment: @ABDULLAH- You are not disturbing me :-) Yes, using `std::find` is the easiest and idiomatic way in this case. But, you could just make a loop to search the vector manually. That's what `std::find` does internally. [Examples](https://godbolt.org/z/r5TEqjMbG)

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't understand the manual example though i guess too advanced for me right now haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do-while loop to iterate the message "5 is already in the list" everything a duplicate integer is given as input.
If you can send the whole code, maybe I can do it for you.

Comment: The code is too big i dont know how to add in the comment!

Comment: Its not about one number, what if user doesen't enter 5? I don't know the logic to set for whatever number user enters.. suppose he enters 330 , and 330 is already in the list, then i want the message to appear like "330 is already in the list" I am failing to do this.

Comment: Do not add code in comments, add it in the question. If it is big, make a [mre].

Comment: I added the full code @abbujaansboy, i want to add this functionality in case A a